# After clicking Button in android studio,I am getting out of app

Tags: android

I had created a Tic Tac Toe game,which created a black and red image user have to create three pair of sets,two user can play,any one whoever made it first will win .I created a Play again button for restarting the game again and again ,but after clicking that button, i am getting out of the app. Can you guys help me where i am going wrong .Below i am giving my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tictac;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //0:cross,1:red,2:empty
    int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
    int activePlayer =0;
    boolean gameActive = true;
    public void dropIn(View view){
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
        if(gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameActive) {
            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;
            counter.setTranslationY(-1500);
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.redd);
                activePlayer = 0;

            }
            counter.animate().translationYBy(1500).rotation(3600).setDuration(300);
            for (int[] winningPositions : winningPositions) {
                if (gameState[winningPositions[0]] == gameState[winningPositions[1]] && gameState[winningPositions[1]] == gameState[winningPositions[2]] && gameState[winningPositions[0]] != 2) {
                    //someone win
                    gameActive = false;
                    String winner = "";
                    if (activePlayer == 1) {
                        winner = "Black";
                    } else {
                        winner = "Red";
                    }

                    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
                    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
                    winnerTextView.setText(winner  + " has won");
                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void okayPlay(View view){
        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)  findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount() ;i++){
            ImageView counter =(ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            counter.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<gameState.length;i++){
            gameState[i]=2;
        }

         activePlayer =0;
         gameActive = true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bd"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.296"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.349" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="164dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:onClick="okayPlay"
        android:text="@string/play_again"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/winnerTextView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share log detail when your app get crash

Comment: Is the app crashing? If so, take a look at the logcat window. That can tell you what line of code is causing the crash. I don't see anything obviously wrong but you may want to consider not using `winningPositions` as both a member variable and a local variable. You should also check the return values from `findViewById` and `getChildAt` to make sure `null` is not being returned.

Comment: One other thing to check is to make sure the children of your grid layout are actually `ImageView`s

Answer (score 2):

Your app is crashing because in your **okayPlay(View view)** method you're trying to cast

> androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout

to

> android.widget.GridLayout

In your Activity, change your `android.widget.GridLayout` import to
`androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`